# How to Collect similar items of a list in groovy

Tags: java, list, grails, collections, groovy

I have a list as below

```
    ordersList=[[id:1, amount:1000, salesPerson:'XYZ'], 
                [id:2, amount:3000, salesPerson:'XYZ'], 
                [id:3, amount:1000, salesPerson:'ABC']
                 ...n items

               ];
```

I want to Collect the items with same value of property 'salesPerson' and total of all the order amount of that 'salesPerson', Finally i want to have list like below, Means a list should be created for each 'salesPerson' and that should contain all the orders with that of 'salesPerson'

Finally, the list i would expect is

```
 salesPersonOrdersList = [xyzSalesPersonOrdersList, abcSalesPersonOrdersList]


    xyzSalesPersonOrdersList = [[name:'XYZ'], orders:[[id:1, amount:1000],[id:2, amount:3000]],[totalAmount:4000] ]

    abcSalesPersonOrdersList = [[name:'ABC'], orders:[[id:3, amount:1000]],[totalAmount:1000] ]
```

How to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupBy` to group the items by name :

```
def ordersList=[[id:1, amount:1000, salesPerson:'XYZ'], 
            [id:2, amount:3000, salesPerson:'XYZ'], 
            [id:3, amount:1000, salesPerson:'ABC']
           ];

ordersList.groupBy{it.salesPerson} 
//------------------------------------------------
//Result: [XYZ:[[id:1, amount:1000, salesPerson:XYZ], [id:2, amount:3000, salesPerson:XYZ]], ABC:[[id:3, amount:1000, salesPerson:ABC]]]
```

Then you can transform the map to fit your needs like :

```
ordersList.groupBy{it.salesPerson}.collect{[name : it.key,orders : it.value]}
//-----------------------------------------------
//Result: [[name:XYZ, orders:[[id:1, amount:1000, salesPerson:XYZ], [id:2, amount:3000, salesPerson:XYZ]]], [name:ABC, orders:[[id:3, amount:1000, salesPerson:ABC]]]]
```